# Sonos player not calling getExtendedMetadata after rating item

Tags: sonos

I am implementing two-button rating for tracks. When the user clicks vote up/down, `rateItem` gets called, and my server returns an empty `rateItemResponse` (I have defined `AutoSkip` and `OnSuccessMessageId` in the presentation map). Immediately afterwards, `getLastUpdate` is called, and my server returns a response with the `favorites` value incremented. However, after the `getLastUpdate` response is returned, `getExtendedMetadata` is not called on the rated track to get the new user rating. What is the specific setup in order for `getExtendedMetadata` to be called after seeing an updated `favorites` value?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to do to get this going, not all of which you mention in your queston. So, in case you haven't done this already, run the test as described here: https://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/376

Specifically note this section on that page:

> There is another test, test_meta_data, in the ratings fixture that verifies that both getExtendedMetadata and getMediaMetadata are implemented correctly. This means that when these SMAPI requests are made with the object ID's listed in the Self-Test config for Test Track and the responses should contain a dynamic tag as part of the mediaMetadata. Inside the dynamic tag you must set property tags, each of which should contain a name and a value which is mapped to in the presentation map.

Also, maybe Sonos doesn't call extendedMetadata because there were no dynamic or property tags (or something) in the initial call's answer (but still the getLastUpdate call is supposted handle that, I think).

EDIT:
This seems to me to be a bug in the sonos customsd system. It should send a getLastUpdate request after a rateItem response, but it doesn't. I expect that this is a known bug, but since I cannot find any SMAPI bug reports sites monitored by Sonos, I am not sure. At any rate, if you are planning to submit you music service to Sonos, they will test it and let you know whether this is also a problem in production.

Any Sonos employees that can shed light on this? (Since the move to Stackoverflow, it seems nearly impossible to contact anybody from Sonos....)

Comment: I have run the Python self-test suite, and it passes all tests, including test_meta_data. Also, in the response to getExtendedMetadata and getMediaMetadata, in the mediaMetadata element, I return a dynamic tag with the correct rating information for the item.